# UItabBar from second view controller but all viewController have UInavigation with back to firstViewController issue

Tags: objective-c, uitabbar, uinavigationcontroller

Let me explain my application first. I have six view controller

- MenuViewController
- FirstViewController
- SecondViewController
- ThirdViewController
- FourthViewController
- FifthViewController

All these 6 ViewControllers are in navigationController. I want to show my "MenuViewController" first at the starting time of the app, after splash screen, which contains 5 buttons (For :FirstViewController, SecondViewController, ThirdViewController, FourthViewController, FifthViewController). In this viewController there will be no TabBarController at the bottom of the page. But other viewController will be in tabbarController. When i touch one of those five button in menuviewController, it will bring me to that corresponding view controller where i can find the tabbarController at the bottom. I can do it with custom coding, positioning and setting image behind them. Here is the code:

AppDelegate.h :

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>
{
    UIImageView *firstTabImageView;
    UIImageView *secondTabImageView;
    UIImageView *thirdTabImageView;
    UIImageView *fourthTabImageView;
    UIImageView *fifthTabImageView;

    UIImage *firstTabImage;
    UIImage *firstTabActiveImage;

    UIImage *secondTabImage;
    UIImage *secondTabActiveImage;

    UIImage *thirdTabImage;
    UIImage *thirdTabActiveImage;

    UIImage *fourthTabImage;
    UIImage *fourthTabActiveImage;

    UIImage *fifthTabImage;
    UIImage *fifthTabActiveImage;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) MenuViewController *menuViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;
```

AppDelegate.m :

```
-(void)makeTabBar
{
    tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tabBarController.delegate=self;


    FirstViewController *firstViewController =[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *firstNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];
    firstNavigationController.tabBarController.tabBar.tag = 0;


    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *secondNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondViewController];
    secondNavigationController.tabBarController.tabBar.tag = 1;

    ThirdViewController *thirdViewController = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *thirdNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:thirdViewController];
    thirdNavigationController.tabBarController.tabBar.tag = 2;

    FourthViewController *fourthViewController = [[FourthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FourthViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *fourthNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:fourthViewController];
    fourthNavigationController.tabBarController.tabBar.tag = 3;

    FifthViewController *fifthViewController = [[FifthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FifthViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *fifthNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:fifthViewController];
    fifthNavigationController.tabBarController.tabBar.tag = 4;


    menuNavigationController.navigationBarHidden   = YES;
    firstNavigationController.navigationBarHidden  = YES;
    secondNavigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    thirdNavigationController.navigationBarHidden  = YES;
    fourthNavigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    fifthNavigationController.navigationBarHidden  = YES;

    NSArray *viewControllers =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:
                           firstNavigationController,
                           secondNavigationController,
                           thirdNavigationController,
                           fourthNavigationController,
                           fifthNavigationController,
                           nil];

    firstTabImage        = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MenuTabImage.png"];
    firstTabActiveImage  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MenuTabImage_Active.png"];

    secondTabImage       = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TVGuideTabImage.png"];
    secondTabActiveImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TVGuideTabImage_Active.png"];

    thirdTabImage        = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FirstRankTabImage.png"];
    thirdTabActiveImage  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FirstRankTabImage_Active.png"];

    fourthTabImage       = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FavoriteTabImage.png"];
    fourthTabActiveImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FavoriteTabImage_Active.png"];

    fifthTabImage        = [UIImage imageNamed:@"RegistrationTabImage.png"];
    fifthTabActiveImage  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"RegistrationTabImage_Active.png"];


    CGRect frame  = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 52);
    UIView *viewa = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    UIImage *tabBarBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Tab_Back.png"];
    UIColor *color = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:tabBarBackgroundImage];
    [viewa setBackgroundColor:color];

    if(IS_IPHONE_5)
    {
        [[self.tabBarController tabBar] insertSubview:viewa atIndex:1];
        firstTabImageView  = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 519, 64, 49)];
        secondTabImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(64, 519,64, 49)];
        thirdTabImageView  = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(128, 519,64, 49)];
        fourthTabImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(192, 519, 64, 49)];
        fifthTabImageView  = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(256, 519, 64, 49)];
    }
    else
    {
        [[self.tabBarController tabBar] insertSubview:viewa atIndex:0];
        firstTabImageView  = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 431, 64, 49)];
        secondTabImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(64, 431,64, 49)];
        thirdTabImageView  = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(128, 431,64, 49)];
        fourthTabImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(192, 431, 64, 49)];
        fifthTabImageView  = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(256, 431, 64, 49)];
    }

    firstTabImageView.image  = firstTabActiveImage;
    secondTabImageView.image = secondTabImage;
    thirdTabImageView.image  = thirdTabImage;
    fourthTabImageView.image = fourthTabImage;
    fifthTabImageView.image  = fifthTabImage;

    [self.tabBarController.view addSubview:firstTabImageView];
    [self.tabBarController.view addSubview:secondTabImageView];
    [self.tabBarController.view addSubview:thirdTabImageView];
    [self.tabBarController.view addSubview:fourthTabImageView];
    [self.tabBarController.view addSubview:fifthTabImageView];
    self.tabBarController.delegate=self;
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex=0;

    [tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:NO];
}

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController1 didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController1
{
    if (viewController1 == [tabBarController1.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0])
    {
        firstTabImageView.image  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MenuTabImage_Active.png"];
        secondTabImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TVGuideTabImage.png"];
        thirdTabImageView.image  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FirstRankTabImage.png"];
        fourthTabImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FavoriteTabImage.png"];
        fifthTabImageView.image  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"RegistrationTabImage.png"];
    }
    else if (viewController1 == [tabBarController1.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1])
    {
        firstTabImageView.image  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MenuTabImage.png"];
        secondTabImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TVGuideTabImage_Active.png"];
        thirdTabImageView.image  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FirstRankTabImage.png"];
        fourthTabImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FavoriteTabImage.png"];
        fifthTabImageView.image  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"RegistrationTabImage.png"];
    }
    else if (viewController1 == [tabBarController1.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2])
    {
        firstTabImageView.image  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MenuTabImage.png"];
        secondTabImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TVGuideTabImage.png"];
        thirdTabImageView.image  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FirstRankTabImage_Active.png"];
        fourthTabImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FavoriteTabImage.png"];
        fifthTabImageView.image  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"RegistrationTabImage.png"];
    }
    else if (viewController1 == [tabBarController1.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3])
    {
        firstTabImageView.image  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MenuTabImage.png"];
        secondTabImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TVGuideTabImage.png"];
        thirdTabImageView.image  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FirstRankTabImage.png"];
        fourthTabImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FavoriteTabImage_Active.png"];
        fifthTabImageView.image  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"RegistrationTabImage.png"];
    }
    else if (viewController1 == [tabBarController1.viewControllers objectAtIndex:4])
    {
        firstTabImageView.image  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MenuTabImage.png"];
        secondTabImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TVGuideTabImage.png"];
        thirdTabImageView.image  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FirstRankTabImage.png"];
        fourthTabImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"FavoriteTabImage.png"];
        fifthTabImageView.image  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"RegistrationTabImage_Active.png"];
    }
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self makeTabBar];

    MenuViewController *menuViewController = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController" bundle:nil];
    navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:menuViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

I use this code for every "IBAction" with different index :
For example : "FirstViewController" with "index: 0"

```
- (IBAction)GotoFirstViewController:(id)sender
{
    AppDelegate *appdelegte = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [[[appdelegte navigationController] view]removeFromSuperview];
    [[appdelegte window] addSubview:[[appdelegte tabBarController] view]];
    [[appdelegte tabBarController] setSelectedIndex:0];
}
```

Now the problem is **after going to a ViewController, and come back to "MenuViewController"**
Useing this code :

```
-(IBAction)goBack:(id)sender
{
    menuViewController = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:menuViewController animated:YES];
}
```

**I cannot go to another ViewController (any of five) pressing the same button.**
If any one know, when the tabbar is setup from "seceondViewController (Here : firstViewController)" then  after coming to the "firstViewController ( here : menuViewController)" from other ViewController, how to go again in the other ViewController which are connected with tabbar, please share with me.
Thanks a lot for reading this post and a lot thanks in advance.
- Tulon

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)addToolBarToView:(UIToolbar *)rootToolBar currentView:(UIViewController *)currentView{

CGRect rect = currentView.view.frame;

rootToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, rect.size.height-44, rect.size.width, 44)];

[rootToolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];

[rootToolBar sizeToFit];

UIBarButtonItem *searchBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_ricerca.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showSearch)];

UIBarButtonItem *cartBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_shopping_cart.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showCart)];

UIBarButtonItem *settingBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_settings.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showSettings)];

UIBarButtonItem *favoriteBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_preferiti.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showFavorites)];

UIBarButtonItem *savedBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_save.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showSaved)];

UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];

NSArray *barItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:searchBtn, flexSpace, cartBtn, flexSpace, favoriteBtn, flexSpace, settingBtn, flexSpace, savedBtn ,nil];

[rootToolBar setItems:barItems animated:YES];

[currentView.view addSubview:rootToolBar];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add this code at your AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    self.tabBarController.selectedViewController=viewController;
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Salam,
This is not working brother. I think, i have to add something in "GotoFirstViewController" button action.

Answer (score 0):

Based on apple documentation UITabBar is a subclass of UIViewController and can be a child View..! But it must be the UIWindow rootController if not your app will crash!!! I had the same problem at the end I had to use UIToolBar to do the same thing.. though with a very hard work on customization.